# Solve $y'' - k^2 xy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In general, to solve second order equations of with non-constant coefficients, must we always try series solutions?

Is there a way to solve:

$y'' - k^2 xy = 0$

for constant k?  Can you just 'guess' the complementary function here though I'm not sure how to do it?

Comment: This is a separable equation.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess my question is then what is int ( y''/y ) dr

Comment: the solution containes no knowing elementary function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the searched solution is given by $$y \left( x \right) ={\it \_C1}\,{{\rm Ai}\left(-\sqrt [3]{-{k}^{2}}x
\right)}+{\it \_C2}\,{{\rm Bi}\left(-\sqrt [3]{-{k}^{2}}x\right)}
$$
$$Ai$$ is the so-called Airy function